# Expo can't Load Fonts

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, expo

I have been trying to load Fonts in Expo but I am getting the same Error over and over.

This is my Code:

My Index.js looks as follows:

```js
import WelcomePage from "./Authentication/WelcomePage";

export default function Page() {

  return (
      <WelcomePage/>
  );
}
```

while my Welcomepage looks like this

```js
import {Link, useRouter} from "expo-router";
import {windowForm} from "../Design/WindowForm";
import {Button} from "react-native-paper";
import Styles from "../Design/styles";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import {Inter_900Black, useFonts} from "@expo-google-fonts/inter";

const WelcomePage = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        Inter_900Black,
    });

    if (!fontsLoaded) {
        return null;
    }
    return(
        <View style={{width: windowForm().at(0), height:windowForm().at(1)}}>
            <Text style={{fontFamily:'Inter_900Black'}}>
                Hey
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
export default WelcomePage
```

and this is the Error I keep getting:

`Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by WelcomePage. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks`

Including this:

Previous Render

1. useState
2. useState
3. useEffect
4. undefined

Next Render

1. useState
2. useState
3. useEffect
4. useState

Comment: And you format that a little better? What's the error, and what is "you adding additional information"? Also, have you turned this into a [mcve] that clearly shows the problem is the fonts, and not something else? (and if you've not created an MCVE, and it looks like you haven't yet: run through that exercise. Because it forces you into figuring out what's part of the problem and what isn't, and almost always lets you find the true problem, obviating the need to even hit "post" on a question you had already written up).

Comment: how does `windowForm` looks like? I suspect it introduces/refers to hooks and is called as an ordinary function and in conditional (`if (...) return null;`) way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to
Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans

I have figured out that I should first do an MCVE. That's how I realised it's not about the Fonts but actually about my `javascript windowForm().at(0)` being called inside the same const as the fonts.

I am not sure why yet but as I separated them it didn't throw an error. As soon as I know more I will edit this post. shout out to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans)